# Django custom manage.py commands calling functions in app

Tags: django, django-1.3

I have a command which is used to download data from an API, and then store it into a local database, it's currently part of my app but I want to add the ability to run it from a manage.py command.

Currently i'm just trying to call it as i would inside my application with the correct arguments but i get an error related to models

Error:

```
  File "C:\xxx\Development\working folder\appdata\globaltags\boughtintags.py", line 2, in <module>
    import appdata.boughtin.models as models
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'models'
```

Current Code i'm using:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = '<queryset_uuid queryset_item_uuid>'
    help = 'Downloads arbitrary items using a download script'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for queryset_uuid, queryset_item_uuid in args:

            if download_queryset(queryset_uuid=queryset_uuid, queryset_item_uuid=queryset_item_uuid):
                self.stdout.write('Successfully downloaded "%s"\n' % queryset_item_uuid)
            else:
                raise CommandError('Unable to download "%s"\n' % queryset_item_uuid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `import appdata.boughtin.models as models` in `boughtintags.py` to

```
from appdata.boughtin import models
```